# Can ant break upon encountering an undefined property?

Tags: ant, undefined

We'd like `ant` to fail early, when it is invoked incorrectly -- when some property is found to be undefined.

By default, however, the tool will substitute the literal `${foo}` in such cases. (It logs this condition -- but only at DEBUG-level.)

Is it possible to change that -- making it fail with something like `foo is undefined`? Some equivalent to `set -u` in bash?

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @martinclayton, we might make use of the explicit `<fail>`. But that'd still require us to check every property ourselves. I'd rather ant just failed upon encountering _anything_ undefined -- especially, the mistyped properties :)

Comment: I think you might be able to do something with a PropertyHelper ... but I probably won't have time to figure out what that might be, and I couldn't find an existing drop-in solution.  The basic idea is to make a helper that fails instead of returning null to the caller, which then does the ${} substitution.